# Merge hashtables with unique keys into one C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How to merge different std::unordered_map into one? Given that all the keys are unique?

For ex:

```
    std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> h1, h2, h3, h4;
    h1.insert({5, 1});
    h1.insert({120, 2});
    h2.insert({7, 4});
    h4.insert({199,1})

std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> h5;
```

Is there a to push all the KeyValue pairs from h1, h2, h3, h4 into the unordered_map h5 in O(1) operation Or Without resorting to hashing all the keys again.

It need not be std::unordered_map only. Any incarnation of hashtable in C++14 would be fine. That provides O(1) insert and query.

Comment: Here's how: open a text editor; write a few lines of C++ to do this, compile, execute, verify the results, fix any errors, repeat until the code works correctly. You're done.

Comment: If [`merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/merge) is what you're after, that's new in C++17.

Comment: aren't hashing operations supposed to be fast enough not to matter too much?

Comment: Do you really need O(1)? Do you know if it's possible at all? And what value should scale? The number of maps? The number of entries? My suggestion: Do as Sam already suggested. Code it. Observe. Learn.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can use `merge` or (`extract` and `insert`) to do exactly this.

```
h5.merge(h1);
h5.merge(h2);
h5.merge(h3);
h5.merge(h4);
```

any duplicates will be left in `h1` through `h4`.  A more manual `extract`/`insert` loop could be written instead, but as `merge` does exactly what you want, no need for that.

This isn't O(1), because a hash map requires work to manage its entries and possibly grow.  But it doesn't rehash, nor does it copy any elements.  It just moves nodes.

In C++11 and 14, you cannot avoid the rehash.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the merge functionality. Any pointers for such implementation which can be adopted?